# Missing expected default Frameworks paths for clang on MacOS (/Library/Frameworks, etc.)

Tags: macos, clang

I am trying to build some fairly simple c++ code that relies on SDL2. Although I have xcode installed, I am invoking clang from the command line and not using xcode.

The SDL2 framework is located under /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework (note that although I reference SDL2 in my post, this problem is not SDL2 specific.)

To pull in the SDL2 dependencies, I specify the SDL2 framework to clang like so:

```
clang -std=c++11 -framework SDL2 test.cpp
```

However when I do this, the SDL headers I include (for example `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`) can't be located. If I pass /Library/Frameworks as a framework search path to clang like so:

```
clang -std=c++11 -F/Library/Frameworks/ -framework SDL2 test.cpp
```

... then everything works. So I can get by. But based on various makefiles I've found around in sample projects, it seems that on Mac OS, the /System/Library/Frameworks and /Library/Frameworks paths are expected to be part of the default set of search paths that clang uses to locate frameworks. This does not seem to be the case for me. If I compare my include paths with what's reported in this [blog post](https://langui.sh/2015/07/24/osx-clang-include-lib-search-paths/), then I'm clearly missing /Library/Frameworks and /System/Library/Frameworks.

Output of `clang -x c -v -E /dev/null`:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name null -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/include -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -o - -x c /dev/null
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Output of `clang -Xlinker -v`:

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-450.3
BUILD 18:16:53 Apr  5 2019
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

I haven't found how to globally specify additional framework paths for clang, but I'm not sure if that's something that's meant to be configured externally or built-in the clang binaries. I do have a workaround, but like I said, based on samples I see on the web, it feels like the expected behaviour would be to have those additional framework include paths somehow included by default.

It doesn't help that combining "framework" to any google search dilutes the real intent of my query.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or what I should look for?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. `SDL2` is not a standard `Framework` (and)
2. `macOS` looks for `Frameworks` in (as shown in the output "***Framework search paths***"):

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/ \
   Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
   ```

If you want don't want to use `-L` then you'll probably want copy the framework there.

Comment: Yes I saw that path in my output. However, would you not consider /System/Library/Framework to be a standard expected location?

As for SDL2 not being a standard Framework, I understand that, but does it have any impact on this problem?

I don't mind manually specifying the framework path to various tools, other than I feel like the behaviour I'm seeing is not standard, e.g. I expected to have /System/Library/Frameworks (at least) as a Framework path that would be implicitly included. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: it seems the SDL instructions are lagging behind Apple's recent changes to move all headers to those paths (rather than say /usr/include or /System/Library/Frameworks)